# What is the are difference beetween micro-frontend and microservice

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, micro-frontend

**Micro-frontend** is a microservice approach to frontend web development.

> **Microservice** is an architectural style that structures an application as a collection of small autonomous services, modeled around a business domain.

But

**What are the main differences beetween micro-frontend and microservices?**.

Answer (score 2):

`Microservices` are related to back-end side functionalities while
`Microfrontends` is related to the frontend & the idea is to divide your application on the client side.
This division is especially helpful when you have a group of many developers working over the same product/codebase.

Take a look at the below links for understanding the difference, the idea of micro-frontends & their pros and cons.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuRB3djraeM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asqgKaUMXq0)

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bnmy5zMY14s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asqgKaUMXq0)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asqgKaUMXq0

Answer (score 0):

Just naming. Microfrontend is client version of microservices. You can implement your frontend as multiple applications (microfrontends). On backend side you create multiple deployables (microservices) to build an application. Of course, there are some patterns and best practices (API Gateway, Service Discovery etc.) for microservices and microfrontends which may not be applicable to one or differ between each other. However the main idea is same.